# Show last modified posts based on post category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

As the title says, I have a problem with the output of last modified posts based on current post category. I found solutions based on either the last modified post or the category, but not both together.

As I'm more Illustrator/Designer with knowledge in HTML and CSS, I don't know how to put this together in php. For somebody who's familiar with coding, I'm sure, it's a question of seconds. What I have now is this:

```
function wpb_lastupdated_posts() { 

// Query Arguments

$lastupdated_args = array(
'orderby' => 'modified',
'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1',
'showposts' => 2
);

//Loop to display 5 recently updated posts
$lastupdated_loop = new WP_Query( $lastupdated_args );
$counter = 1;
$string .= '<ul>';
while( $lastupdated_loop->have_posts() && $counter < 5 ) : 
$lastupdated_loop->the_post();
$string .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $lastupdated_loop->post->ID 
) . '"> ' .get_the_title( $lastupdated_loop->post->ID ) . '</a> ( '. 
get_the_modified_date('d.m,') . get_the_modified_time() .' ) </li>';
$counter++;
endwhile; 
$string .= '</ul>';
return $string;
wp_reset_postdata(); 
} 

//add a shortcode
add_shortcode('lastupdated-posts', 'wpb_lastupdated_posts');
```

I added the shortcode in the sidebar and it puts out my last modified posts as expected, but unfortunately it's missing the based-on-category-in-which-the-post-is-php.

Could please somebody help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update your shortcode to accept a parameter for category id.

On your wp query arguments, Use that id.

```
function wpb_lastupdated_posts( $atts ) { 

// Query Arguments

$lastupdated_args = array(
 'orderby' => 'modified',
 'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1',
 'showposts' => 2,
 'cat' => $atts['catid']
);
```

When calling the shortcode, pass the current category id.

```
[lastupdated-posts catid="current_cat_id_here"]
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin.
This could be a part of the solution. But I need to output the last updated posts automatically, best dynamic (based on sub or parent category -, where the post is in). So that the category-class is passed to the last-updated posts (i hope i think in the right direction). Maybe there is a tweak for the shortcode like this:
    [lastupdated-posts catid='---CATEGORY CLASS THAT THE BODY HAS AT THE MOMENT---']

Comment: @Lukasz to get the category of the current post you could use "get_the_category( )" function of wordpress. Pass the current ID to this function. To get The current post ID, you could use "get_queried_object_id()".

`get_the_category( get_queried_object_id() )`. This will return an Array of WP_Term objects, one for each category assigned to the post. You could then loop it to get the category IDS.

Comment: This sounds good. As mentioned, I'm not very familiar with php, so with this given info, i'm not able to put it in php. Could you provide me an example-snippet how and where to put it in? Should i put it in my existing function "wpb_lastupdated_posts"?